# How to stream C preprocessing?

Tags: stream, c-preprocessor

I want to process the output of `cpp` as it is being generated. Unfortunately it looks like the `cpp` version I'm using (5.4.0) buffers up at least 100MB of output before emitting *anything*. As a simple test:

```
% cpp -
#define B A A A A A A A A A
#define C B B B B B B B B B
#define D C C C C C C C C C
#define E D D D D D D D D D
#define F E E E E E E E E E
#define G F F F F F F F F F
#define H G G G G G G G G G
H H H H H H H H H H H H H H
```

Nothing is generated until the input is terminated with ctrl-D. Not just that, but also `cpp` stalls for several seconds and consumes 2GB of RAM before emitting anything!

How do I preprocess C code without excessive buffering?

Comment: `How to stream C preprocessing?` Write or use a C preprocessor that does that. (?) `How do I preprocess C code without excessive buffering?` By using or writing a C preprocessor that doesn't buffer. `like the cpp version I'm using (5.4.0)` How did you check the version? gcc 5.4 is 7 years old. Install newer one.